# Convert varchar(40) to datetime column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `date` column and it is of type `varchar(40)` 
I want to convert it to `datetime`

Please let me know if below command is correct to convert to `datetime`

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `date` = str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%m-%Y' );
```

The table has thousands of records. For example, `date` has value `10/21/2016 15:02` for one record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

First, your str_to_date() format must match the format of the input string. If your input string is `10/21/2016 15:02`, then your format is `%m/%d/%Y %H:%i`.

See a reference for the format codes here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Second, using UPDATE doesn't change the data type of the column, it just changes the content of the varchar string.

```
mysql> create table t (v varchar(50));

mysql> insert into t values ('10/21/2016 15:02');

mysql> update t set v = str_to_date(v, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i');

mysql> select * from t;
+---------------------+
| v                   |
+---------------------+
| 2016-10-21 15:02:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Now it's in the right format, but it's still a varchar.

```
mysql> alter table t modify v datetime;

mysql> select * from t;
+---------------------+
| v                   |
+---------------------+
| 2016-10-21 15:02:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Now the data type has been changed.

```
mysql> show create table t\G

CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `v` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```