# Parsing Custom Date Format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date-formatting

### Problem

I need to query out a date value for use in some ETL processing. However, the data is stored in MySQL as a `VARCHAR` column in values like `1/1/19`.

### What I've tried

A simple `CAST(myDateColumn as DATE)` fails as I get values like `0001-01-19` returned back.

### Question

Am I able to pass a custom date format string into the `CAST` call somehow to tell it how to parse out the date parts? If not, could a `SUBSTRING` type of function help here?

Comment: Have you read the docs on the [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function?

Comment: Why not fix your data set?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861550/convert-varchar40-to-datetime-column/47861625#47861625

Comment: Dataset isn't mine to fix, unfortunately. @BillKarwin That `STR_TO_DATE()` looks like the ticket!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, you can use the STR_TO_DATE() function to parse a string into a proper YYYY-MM-DD date.

Comment: For this example specifically, if someone needs it, it ended up being `STR_TO_DATE(myDateColumn, '%m/%d/%Y')`.